# Create a list of objects in C++

Tags: c++

I have a fair amount of knowledge in Python, but I'm transitioning over to C++. I have a program that's asking for a number from the user and will continue to loop until the user enters in a certain number to stop. What I need to do is to create a list of the numbers entered in by the user, then when the loop is done, find the maximum, minimum, and average of the numbers. In Python, this was done by just declaring an empty list, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this in C++. Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: You could use an `std::vector<int>` to hold the numbers. But you don't really need a list to calculate min, max and average.

Comment: This is going to sound stupid, but can the vector hold an infinite amount of items until the user enters in the right number to break out of the loop? And if so, how can you append the number into the vector?

Comment: If you have a computer with infinite memory and the means to address it then yes.

Comment: Ok. So I have the program written where when the user enters a number, there are about 5 if/else statements to determine what rank the number is. How can I then place that number into the vector? Is it as simple as: vector<exampleNum>?

Comment: You know, SO is not a good place to ask "how do I do this very basic thing in language X". It's be different if the answer was not so obvious, but I bet every C++ introduction, tutorial and book go over `std::vector` as soon as it covers `for` loop...

Answer (score 2):

I don't have sufficient rep. to comment, so here's an implementation. The push_back() function of std::vector is what you're looking for. www.cplusplus.com is my favorite online reference for the STL: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const int STOP_NUM = 0;
   cout << "Enter numbers. " << STOP_NUM << " to stop." << endl;

   vector<int> myNums;
   int num;

   while( cin >> num && num != STOP_NUM )
      myNums.push_back(num);

   if( myNums.size() > 0 )
   {
      int min=myNums[0], max=myNums[0], sum=0;
      for( const auto &num : myNums )
      {
         sum += num;
         if( num < min ) min = num;
         if( num > max ) max = num;
      }

      cout << "min: " << min << "\n";
      cout << "max: " << max << "\n";
      cout << "avg: " << static_cast<float>(sum)/myNums.size() << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: I suggest actually displaying `STOP_NUM`, and avoiding flushing `cout` more than necessary.

Comment: Updated with your suggestions.

Comment: @tweej Instead of loops, you could simply call `std::max_element` and `std::min_element` to get the maximum and minimum value,or if C++ 11 `std::minmax_element`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I could have used std::accumulate for the sum as well, but that would have iterated the container thrice. There is potential for further optimization by skipping the first element, but it requires more code.

Comment: You really need to break out of the `for` loop on input failure. Otherwise the code will go into an infinite loop. Change to `while ( cin >> num && num != STOP_NUM ) myNums.push_back(num);`

Comment: Thanks! I never considered that cin would return a status.

Answer (score 0):

The first implementation I provided follows your requirements. This implementation does not, but it'll use much less memory for moderate to large amount of numbers entered. The potential for overflow of sum still exists with this implementation (as well as for cnt, now).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const int STOP_NUM = 0;
   cout << "Enter numbers. " << STOP_NUM << " to stop." << endl;

   bool first = true;
   int num;
   int min, max, sum=0, cnt=0;

   while( cin >> num && num != STOP_NUM )
   {
      if(first)
      {
         min = max = sum = num;
         first = false;
      }
      else
      {
         sum += num;
         if( num < min ) min = num;
         if( num > max ) max = num;
      }
      ++cnt;
   }

   if( cnt > 0 )
   {
      cout << "min: " << min << "\n";
      cout << "max: " << max << "\n";
      cout << "avg: " << static_cast<float>(sum)/cnt << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: While this is a useful way to "find the maximum, minimum, and average of the numbers", it does not answer the question, which is about "Create a list of objects in C++".

Comment: Instead of posting a second answer, you should edit your existing answer. Hence flagged for deletion.

Comment: Ok, noted. Still new at answering.